# Eclipse Lost Android Support After Windows Update

Tags: java, android, eclipse

After a windows system update, Eclipse know longer knows anything about Android... how do I get android support back?  I tried reinstalling the SDK, but that didn't work...

So strange.  I notice the project template is missing, so I can't quickly recreate the project.  I'm using the latest version of eclipse.

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling the plugin... SDK would still be there, so no need to reinstall it.

Comment: Worked, thanks.  I hope I don't have to go through this for every windows update......